# alphanumeric value in versionproperty of visual studio installer

Tags: c#, asp.net, installation

Can we have alphanumeric value like v2.1.0.xyx.1 in version property of web installers in visual studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible.

The [`Version`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.aspx) class parts are all typed as `int32`, so you can't give them a string value.

Comment: can we have any altenate solution for this.Actually while deploying product using installers to diffrent clients ,it's confusing to have 1.1.0.Is there is any other way to distinguish two installers going to 2 different client.

Comment: @Shipu - I don't have a good answer for you. Give the products a different name, perhaps?